# How do I scale test score improvements with normally distributed test scores?

Tags: statistical-significance, normalization

I have data on an entire population's test scores at two points in time. The entire set of test scores are normally distributed. There are 10 groups in the population. I want to be able to identify whether some groups improved more/less than others. Each group has a different Test 1 mean score, which means that, even if they all improved by 5 points, I don't know how to determine with confidence which group improved the most relatively.

Example data:

```
Group   Test 1 mean   Test 2 mean   change
A       78            83            5
B       82            85            3
C       84            86            2
```

But because the scores are normally distributed, group C's improvement from an 84 to an 86 might be just as significant of an improvement as group A moving 5 points from 78 to an 83. The reason I bring up the normal distribution of the scores is because, looking at the CDF plot of these scores, it points toward the necessity of scaling. I.E. 99% of people scored 35 or higher and 98% of people scored 50 or higher, but only 1% of people scored 90 or higher and .01% of people scored 95 or higher, so we can see that its harder to continue increasing your score from test 1 to test 2 as your initial score gets higher. This is really easy for me to understand intuitively, but I can't seem to figure out how to quantify this score scaling. A log transformation was suggested, which makes sense to me, be I can't seem to figure out how to actually validate that whatever log function I am applying to the scores is actually correctly scaling these scores.

edit: for further clarification, I believe my question is similar to [How to conduct a test for two groups on percentage increase to account for scaling differences?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/345015/119439) except that, in my case, everyone takes the same test both times, AND I have the entire population data so I can know the population test score distribution.

2nd edit: include sample data

Comment: Did you start by writing down your hypothesis you wanted to test?

Comment: @jsb I think there are two hypotheses where the second relies on the first. The null hypothesis for the second is that all groups had the same relative score improvements. The first i'm not sure about, but roughly I want to say that each increment in score is more difficult/less likely the than the last

Comment: I think you should transform/scale the scores first.i.e. in the current situation, the score does not reflect how longer it is the distance of effort between 95 and 100, compared to distance of effort between 65 and 70. Both has distance 5, yet represents different distance of effort. You should transform/scale it in a way that the transformed values account for this, then move from there.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 I agree, but that is the main thing I am stuck on. In my brain, this looks like making the CDF plot linear, so that each incremental increase in transformed score has the same probability. but I'm not sure how to develop this transofmration

Comment: Log scale transformation $Y=log(X)$ weighs distance from 1 to 10 as equal to distance from 10 to 100. Because we want the opposite, $Y=log(100-X)$ may help, because it weighs distance from 0 to 90 as equal to distance from 90 to 99. You can go from there and adjust the transformation accordingly. I don't know what transformation may help exactly in your case, but log transformation comes to mind easily to shrink/expand distances in scale.

Comment: @Nuclear03020704 Thank you. log transformation is definitely in the right direction, but I am still not understanding how I validate that whatever log function I apply has given back the "correct" scaled data. Correct meaning that, according to the actual test score data distribution, the scaled scores accurately reflect how much more "difficult" it is to go from 95 to 100 than 65 to 85. Again, I picture this as seeing some graph become linear, but I don't know what one/how to arrive there.

Comment: @ac927 I think it would be helpful to edit your question to include some of what you have now explained in the comments.

Comment: @mdewey agree. I edited and hopefully added some clarity